# Can't manage to write to Console or Debug panel using Visual Studio 2017 C# .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-community

I have a small program in C# .NET on VS2017 Community. I can't mangage to write anything to the Console, when launching the program from there. I can't manage either to write anything to the debug panel in VS2017 while debugging.

I tried those 3 differents lines :

```
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("test");
```

I tried both Windows Application and Console Application.
I'm a bit lost now... any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you all in adavance.

Encore.

Comment: Is the program running, then finishing successfully?

Comment: what do you mean by *"when launching from there"*? Is this only reproing when you launch it a particular way? When you set a breakpoint at the first line, does it get hit? What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: In the output pane, are you showing the output from 'Debug'?

Comment: Yes the program runs correctly, there is some code called right after thoses 3 lines, that generates a file.
Sorry, I just hit the ENTER button on the keyboard expeting it to write a carriage return... trying to answer your other questions now.

Comment: Put a Console.ReadKey() or breakpoint at the bottom. Then the output should show, since the program is "paused".

Comment: When launching from there -> when launching from a cmd.

Comment: Oh... wait.....

Comment: Ok, I just understood something (I can't explain right now) trying to answer your question avout the breakpoints : the class "MainWindow" is not called, for some reason. It starts direectly with Program.Main()

Comment: Are you sure the program isn't erroring out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160230/discussion-between-encore-and-wyatt-shuler).

Comment: I was able to call the MainWindow instead of directly calling the Program.Main. So I added a breackpoint on the 3rd line (System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("test");).
It still doesn't provide any outing if I am in Windows Application.
If I use Console Application, the 1st line works in Debug. The 2nd line works if I launch the program from a cmd.